# Error while adding vaadin to Spring boot project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, vaadin, pom.xml

I have these errors while adding Vaadin to my Spring boot project (I'm using Intellij IDEA):

```
Cannot resolve plugin com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:${vaadin.version}
Cannot resolve com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:${vaadin.version}
```

This is the relevant part in the pom.xml that is the same proposed on the website of vaadin:

```
        <<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <!-- declare the latest Vaadin version
                 as a property or directly here -->
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            vaadin-spring-boot-starter
        </artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- The Spring Boot Maven plugin for easy
             execution from CLI and packaging -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-maven-plugin
            </artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <!--
            Takes care of synchronizing java
            dependencies and imports in package.json and
            main.js files. It also creates
            webpack.config.js if does not exist yet.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I fix it?
I need to configure something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you are missing a `<vaadin.version>VersionYourWantToUse</vaadin.version>` [property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#properties) from your `<properties>` snippet in pom.xml. For example, Vaadin spring boot starter has this section in its [`pom.xml` file](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-spring/blob/v14/pom.xml#L12) :

```xml
   <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <vaadin.version>14.1.25</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
```

And as the comment in your snippet states you can replace reference to the `${vaadin.version}` with the value directly (like `<version>14.1.25</version>`) or use the `<properties>` as shown above.